# Can a Demon make a gadget with an Exploit or Embed they can't perform?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Can a demon make a gadget to perform an exploit or embed that their character doesn't have? I can see two arguments:

- No: If you don't know the supernatural ability, you don't know how to create it.
- Yes: I can't fly, but I can make a paper airplane that does, or eventually make a hang glider. Gadget fabrication is an extended action, and investing time and materials allows me to create that ability.

Answer (score 2):

## Exploits definitely not, Embeds probably not.

Page 139 of Flowers of Hell: the Demon Player's Guide says the following:

> Instead of priming the object with Aether, the demon simply
> pulls forth the Exploit and pushes it onto the object until it bends
> under his will.

As a result, creating an Exploited Gadget without knowing the Exploit the Gadget is going to use is definitely impossible. By contrast, the segment on the creation of Embedded Gadgets on p. 138 of that book implies that the Demon needs to know the Embed, but doesn't explicitly state it:

> Once the item is primed, the demon concentrates on the
> specific effect he wants to Install in the object. He pushes the
> item towards that effect as he simultaneously pulls the effect
> into reality. Alignment of the two dictates the exact effect the
> demon can Embed in the gadget.

In order to "pull the effect into reality", he'd presumably need to know the Embed in question, so I'd definitely rule that they do need to know the Embed in a game I was running, but the book doesn't explicitly say that they do anywhere I can find.